# How to read local json import in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a JSON file in the flutter directory, not in assets.

json_data.json:-

```
 {
    "foo" : "bar"
 }
```

I want to read this JSON on different files.

like

myfile.dart:-

```
 import "package:mypackage/json_data.json" as data;
 import 'dart:convert';
 
  var my_data = json.decode(data);
```

I am getting the error:-

```
The name 'data' refers to an import prefix, so it must be followed by '.'.
Try correcting the name to refer to something other than a prefix, or renaming the prefix.
```

What is the problem here? why can't I read JSON from local import in flutter?

Comment: because ```json.decode()``` takes a ```string``` as source. I would suggest reading the JSON file as string using ```readAsString``` then pass to ```json.decode```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should look into loading [assets in flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images). You can't simply import an arbitrary file. Importing is for source code/libraries.

You need to declare this file as an asset in your `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - json_data.json
```

Then in your code you can load this asset as a `String`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

Future<String> getJson() {
  return rootBundle.loadString('json_data.json');
}
```

You can decode the JSON with your existing code, but it should be placed in a method body somewhere. You call this `getJson` function to retrieve the JSON String:

```dart
var my_data = json.decode(await getJson());
```

---

Alternatively, you could simplify this even further by putting the contents of your JSON file directly into the code as a `String`, but this may not be possible, it depends on your intended use of this JSON.

```dart
const String data = '''
{
  "foo" : "bar"
}
''';
var my_data = json.decode(data);
```

Comment: What if i want to replace that json file at run time? can i live-update the file inside assets folder while the app is still running?

Comment: @kakyo Assets are not files. There is no assets folder available at runtime. If you want to replace the file, do not use assets.

Comment: @kakyo If you want to replace the file at runtime, then you'll want to host the file online somewhere that your app will then retrieve. You should version it or something, so that your app won't needlessly download the same file over and over until the file has been updated.