# Read a local JSON file and filter its results via textbox

Tags: json, android-studio, flutter, listview, dart

I've found a guide that explained how to populate a listview with the objects from a local JSON file, but from what I can tell this isn't useful as I need to make a List<> of the objects from the JSON file so I can then use the ".Where(" function on it.

However that returned the issue back to "how do I read a local JSON file into a list" as for some reason every guide I've found in over seven hours has only used god damned HTTP stored JSON files.

I am seeking an example or something for Local JSON files being used to create a listview that I can filter through via a textbox.

Video of what sort of goal I have:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUOjcER6DFE

The JSON File content example:

```
[
    {
      "name" : "First",
      "types" : [ "Type one" , "Type two"]
      "number" : "7"
    }
]
```

the JSON file is saved in an assets folder like this:
[image: Inside an assets folder]

Comment: share json value

Comment: @griffins I've added info on what the contents of the JSOn file and where it was stored

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question is that you want to read the local JSON file on Flutter.

You can follow these steps:

1. Add the JSON file to the assets of pubspec.yaml, For example,

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/data.json
```

2. Import

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'
```

3. Use `rootBundle.loadString` method to load JSON file

```
String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/data.json");
```

4. Convert String to JSON

```
final jsonResult = json.decode(jsonString);
```

hope helpful ^_^

Answer (score 0):

> You should look into loading assets in flutter. You can't simply
> import an arbitrary file. Importing is for source code/libraries.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

You can find the correct steps in the answer here: [How to read local json import in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653299/how-to-read-local-json-import-in-flutter)

Adding to that,Jsondecode will return an Object type variable which can then be used with JSON serialisation. So using that you can directly create a list of Data objects directly from the newly created Object. Here is the link for JSON serialisation :

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json