# Flutter: Json File not loading when running on connected device or built to apk

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart

My flutter app works fine when running on an android emulator. But if i run it on my device, or build to an apk and install on a device. The json read returns null

```
 FutureBuilder(
                future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
                    .loadString('assets/diys.json'));
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For using this DefaultAssetBundle.of(context) try to change rootBundle

Code: rootBundle.loadString(your_file_path)

Refer to this accepted answer. [How to read local json import in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653299/how-to-read-local-json-import-in-flutter)