# how do i load the json data from asset folder

Tags: json, flutter

I m unable to load tha data from the file

main.dart

[image]

main

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read local json import in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653299/how-to-read-local-json-import-in-flutter)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text. Copy the original text to your question and use the code format tool.